# Running total only covering range of cells with data

Tags: ssas, mdx

Using the illustrated mockup

(**Note not all DimB members show so the total for DimA is larger than the sum of the displayed DimB, ignore this**):

Query is showing (months,revenue) on 0, (dima,dimb) on 1 from cube
[image]

I would like some assistance in creating the calculated member that would calculate the running total across "Months" here (**not a real time dimension**).

Earlier i was using this one, but it was wrong on so many levels:

```
[Measures].[Accumulated Revenue] = 
IIF(
        ([DimMonths].[Months].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Revenue]) = 0
    AND ([DimMonths].[Months].CurrentMember.NextMember,[Measures].[Revenue]) = 0
    ,
    IIF(
        AGGREGATE({
            [DimMonths].[Months].CurrentMember :
            [DimMonths].[Months].Parent.LastChild 
        },[Measures].[Revenue]) = 0
        ,
        NULL
        ,
        Aggregate( {
            [DimMonths].[Months].Parent.FirstChild : 
            [DimMonths].[Months].CurrentMember.PrevMember
        }
        ,[Measures].[Revenue])
        )
    ,
    Aggregate( {
        [DimMonths].[Months].Parent.FirstChild : 
        [DimMonths].[Months].CurrentMember
        }
    ,[Measures].[Revenue])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a "scoped assignment".  Basically, using a scoped assignment, you can overwrite the value of your calculated measure along the [Member_DimA_01] slice so that these values represent a running total instead of a sum of children.

[Here's a good tutorial from Chris Webb on scoped assignments to help get you started...](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event8/Fun_with_Scoped_Assignments_in_MDX)

Edit: here's a template for the running total calculation...

```
WITH 
SET [Months] AS
    {
        [Date].[Calendar Month].&[2011 - Jan]
        :
        [Date].[Calendar Month].&[2011 - Dec]
    }
MEMBER [Measures].[Running Total] AS
    SUM(
         {
            [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Calendar Month].&[2011 - Jan]
            :
            [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember
         }
        ,[Measures].[Revenue]
    )
SELECT  
    NON EMPTY{
        [Months]
    } ON 0,
    NON EMPTY{
        [DimA].[Member].Allmembers *
        [DimB].[Member].Allmembers
    } ON 1
FROM
    [<<cube name>>]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Revenue Running Total]
```

Comment: Thanks for this link, i will spend some time analyzing it. However i think (and could be wrong) - is that the main issue here is to have ssas understand quickly which cells should be calculated and which shouldn't. When it needs to evaluate each cell before figuring out if it should be empty or not, performance drops. I might just have to accept the current performance and blank cells (it's fast, but has blanks, for example dimb5 for month02 is empty because the revenue is empty (NON_EMPTY_BEHAVOIR).

Comment: apologies, I didn't realize the cells in the grid were also supposed to display running totals.  guess I got caught up with the "range of cells" phrase in the title and only noticed the running total being applied to the subtotal in bold.